# Inkscape export format

Tags: vector, inkscape, png, transparency

I have some vector objects created in Inkscape and I am exporting them to a png files. I am using the exported images in another program.

The problem is, that even though the initial object is on transparent background, the resulting png has a thin white border around it which looks just terrible.

I have read somewhere, that the deafult export format is PNG-8, which should have transparent-functionality, but this feature is often not 100% supported (especially in older versions of software). Is exporting svg objects to PNG-24 a solution to this? I would try it but I have not found how to change the defualt export format in Inkscape.

What else could be done to eliminate this problem? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What are you viewing the created PNG in? I found this FAQ here: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#The_PNGs_exported_by_Inkscape_have_jagged_edges.2Fno_antialiasing.2Ffunny_background.

Comment: We can not reproduce this behaviour here. All exported PNG are borderless as expected. Could it be that the border you observe is a placeholder frame drawn from the importing application?

Comment: Funny thing is, that "saving" the picture as SVG works fine, but "exporting" as SVG does not... I dont know what causes this problem, but I solved simply by not using export anymore (I think that this option provides worse quality of the output, but its ok since these pictures are really small in size..)

Comment: that's weird - I'm trying to find the opposite: the export is 24 bit png for me, and I'm looking for a way to change to 8. I'm using inkscape 0.48 on Ubintu. What is yours?

Comment: What colour is your document background? it should be white/100% transparent by default, but if it's somehow been set to 100% opaque, you'll get a white background on your png exports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After researching this issue, I found [this similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684105/export-as-bitmap-from-inkscape-has-poor-quality) (incorrectly posted BTW).

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4781673/1003940) was:

> I would actually export it as a SVG open it with **Gimp**, do additional
> stuff if required and then save it as a PNG using Gimps save for web
> function.

Also found this FAQ

## [Inkscape FAQ Question](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#The_PNGs_exported_by_Inkscape_have_jagged_edges.2Fno_antialiasing.2Ffunny_background.)

> **The PNGs exported by Inkscape have jagged edges/no antialiasing/funny
> background.**
>
> This is a problem with whatever you use to view these PNG
> files, not with Inkscape. For example, Internet Explorer prior to
> version 7 cannot show PNG files with transparency properly. Use e.g.
> Firefox to view your PNGs. If you absolutely must support IE 6, you
> can't have transparent background in PNG; change it to opaque in
> Document Preferences and export the PNG file again. Also, you should
> look into using Dean Edwards' IE7 Library: It fixes many CSS issues
> and makes transparent PNG work correctly under IE5 and IE6. If you
> want to open the exported PNG bitmaps in MS-Word, you will also have
> to change the alpha-opacity (in document-properties dialog) to full,
> and then export -- the result will be much better.